# How to add argparser subcommands for a specific mode in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I want to run my application in different modes, for example:

```
python3 ./myapp.py --mode server
```

To do this, I created an argument parser and specified modes based on choices:

```
    _parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='some application')
    _parser.add_argument('--mode', dest='mode', action='store',  nargs=1, required=True,
                        choices={'server', 'client', 'stat', 'cli'}, help='Run app in selected mode')
```

In 'cli' mode, I want to specify additional parameters, for example:

```
python3 ./myapp.py --mode cli run-command --with-arguments
```

How to make such an option for processing arguments? Use a subparser for each mode instead of selecting from a 'choices'? Or are there other ways?

Comment: subparsers is effectively a `positional` argument with `choices`, and specialized `action`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subparser. AFAIK, arguments don't support nesting like you want.